# Converting custom javascript noise/offset functions to p5's native functions

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I took a sketch from Processing's Java version and adapted it to `p5.js` that creates a field of nice wavy lines.

But I am learning `p5.js` and looking to simplify the code further by getting the noise and the offset values through p5's in-built functions like `noise()`, `lerp()` etc.

I am trying a lot to get my head over achieving the 2 functions,
`periodicFunction()` and `offset()` and the value of `t` somehow with `p5`'s own helper functions but no luck yet.

I watched **Daniel Shiffman's** amazing [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZI1dmHv3MeM) on *Polar Perlin Noise Loops* several times but still can't progress because instead of linking the noise values to a circular shape (like in his video), I want to adapt it to my sketch here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code:**

```js
function setup()
    {
      createCanvas(500,500);
    }
    
    let numFrames = 80;
    
    function periodicFunction(p)
    {
      return 1.0*sin(TWO_PI*p);
    }
    
    function offset( x, y)
    {
      return 0.005*(x - 2 * y);
    }
    
    function draw()
    {
      background(255);
      
      let t = 1.0*frameCount/numFrames;
      
      let m = 50;
      
      stroke(0);
      
      for(let i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
        for(let j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
          let x = map(i,0,m-1,0,width);
          let y = map(j,0,m-1,0,height);
          
          push();
          translate(x,y);
          
          let rot = periodicFunction(t-offset(x,y));
          rotate(rot);
          
          line(-5,0,5,0);
          pop();
        }
      }
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really sure what the desired result is. What's the goal and how is it that the current code fails to achieve it, exactly? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen the code works fine on p5 editor. I just need a way to get values achieved by the functions `periodicFunction()` and `offset()` and the value of `t` through `p5`'s in-built functions instead. Right now they are achieved by purely javascript coding without using the noise(), lerp(), constrain() etc functions that `p5` already provides to make the task a little less daunting. So I want to use these in-built functions instead but how to go about that where I am stuck. I have provided the online p5.js editor link in the OP so you may run it there.

Answer (score 1):

**The code cannot be simplified any further with P5.js built-in API functions.** From my understanding, the [P5.js API is a subset of the full Processing API](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Processing-transition#overview-of-differences) with a few changes due to the differences between JavaScript and Java.

The Processing API already includes [lerp()](https://processing.org/reference/lerpColor_.html), [noise()](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html), and [constrain()](https://processing.org/reference/constrain_.html). So there is no reason the original Processing script could not use these functions.

Furthermore, your code doesn't use any noise, lerping, or constraining. Let me explain why the functions cannot be simplified:

```
function periodicFunction(p)
{
  return 1.0*sin(TWO_PI*p);
}
```

Function `periodicFunction()` simply scales the `sin()` function's amplitude by 1.0 and frequency by 1/TWO_PI. You can replace `periodicFunction()` with just `sin().` The effect will be basically the same, although more "stretched" or "compressed."

```
function offset( x, y)
{
  return 0.005*(x - 2 * y);
}
```

The function `offset()` simply calculates an "offset" value based on the x and y coordinates. This causes the "diagonal" effect because different parts of the sine wave are being used based on the x,y values. If you replace `offset()` with a constant like 0, all the "waves" will appear to line up.

```
let t = 1.0*frameCount/numFrames;
```

Finally, the value of `t` is calculated to give a value that slowly increases between frames. Using `frameCount` may help keep the animation more smooth? You could modify this to increase by a constant like `t += 0.1;` (if `t` is initialized outside this function).

Note: I think the pattern `1.0* ...` is used several times to coerce integer values into floating point values. Otherwise `frameCount/numFrames` may result in integer values. This doesn't seem to be necessary in JavaScript (`3/2` is 1.5 in JS).

I have made all the simplifications described above in the snippet below. As you can see, the basic animation is similar; just less interesting:

```js
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(500,500);
}

function periodicFunction(p)
{
  return sin(p); // Simplified to simple sin() function.
}

function offset( x, y)
{
  return 0;      // Simplified to return a constant value.
}

let t = 0;       // Need to declare/initialize outside function.
function draw()
{
  background(255);

  t += 0.1;      // Simplified to increment by constant value;

  let m = 50;

  stroke(0);

  for(let i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for(let j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      let x = map(i,0,m-1,0,width);
      let y = map(j,0,m-1,0,height);

      push();
      translate(x,y);

      let rot = periodicFunction(t-offset(x,y));
      rotate(rot);

      line(-5,0,5,0);
      pop();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

---

**update:** Here is an example of how to incorporate noise into the sketch. Variable `t` is incremented randomly, but smoothly using noise so the animation seems to randomly speed up and slow down:

```js
function setup()
{
  createCanvas(500,500);
}

let numFrames = 80;

function periodicFunction(p)
{
  return 1.0*sin(TWO_PI*p);
}

function offset( x, y)
{
  return 0.005*(x - 2 * y);
}

let t = 0
function draw()
{
  background(255);

  t += noise(frameCount/100)/40;  // Increment randomly, but smoothly using noise.

  let m = 50;

  stroke(0);

  for(let i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for(let j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      let x = map(i,0,m-1,0,width);
      let y = map(j,0,m-1,0,height);

      push();
      translate(x,y);

      let rot = periodicFunction(t-offset(x,y));
      rotate(rot);

      line(-5,0,5,0);
      pop();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```